# How to remove weirdly forced spaces between lines in a paragraph?

Tags: line-spacing

I am using the following linespacing setup:

```
\captionsetup{belowskip=0pt}

\skip\footins 0.5\baselineskip
\floatsep \baselineskip
\textfloatsep \baselineskip
\intextsep \baselineskip 
\dbltextfloatsep \baselineskip  
\dblfloatsep \baselineskip 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{0.5\baselineskip}{0pt}
\titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
```

And I am getting some weird big space between paragraphs as follows:

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening...
In addition, I am using the following template: https://www.acm.org/publications/proceedings-template

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not obvious how you produce the two-column text. But google "ragged bottom" or edit the question with a MWE.